# How to check if there are multiple values of the same attribute in the same object, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables: Products, PRO_FAB and Fabrics. Products table has Product_ID and Name, PRO_FAB Has PRO_FAB_ID, Product_ID and Fabric_ID, Fabrics have Fabric_ID and Name. They are related like this:

```
Products.Product_ID --- PRO_FAB.Product_ID <-> PRO_FAB.Product_ID --- Fabrics.Fabric_ID.
```

So it's basically a m:n relationship. I'm trying to make a query that will list a Product that is made out of all fabrics in the Fabrics table. I've tried using HAVING, CONTAINS and other methods, but none seems to work, or at least I don't know how to use them. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @TotalFabrics int
SELECT @TotalFabrics = count(*) FROM dbo.Fabrics

SELECT p.Name
FROM Products p
  INNER JOIN PRO_FAB pf ON pf.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
  INNER JOIN Fabrics f ON f.Fabric_ID = pf.Fabric_ID
GROUP BY p.Name
HAVING COUNT(f.Fabric_ID) = @TotalFabrics
```

This should work if you're looking for products that use ALL fabrics. Would be interested to see what other approaches people will come up with.

You can also replace @TotalFabrics with a subquery if needed, but I think this is neater.

Comment: Nice! I knew it was something to do with HAVING :D Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

As Dmitri correctly pointed out, the following query gets products with ANY fabrics, not ALL fabrics (I read the question too fast and didn't take the time to understand it).

```
SELECT Fabrics.Name as FabricName, Products.Name as ProductName
FROM Fabrics
 INNER JOIN PRO_FAB pf on Fabrics.FabricID = pf.FabricID
 INNER JOIN Products on Products.ProductID = pf.ProductID
ORDER BY FabricName, ProductName
```

Dmitri's solution is elegant and easy to understand (and I'm sure it performs better, so I've given it an up vote), but I thought of another solution that will work (I'm sure there are many more)

```
;with cte as
(
  SELECT     Products.Product_ID, Fabrics.Fabric_ID
  FROM         Fabrics CROSS JOIN Products
)
Select Products.Name
FROM Products
WHERE Product_ID 
NOT IN(SELECT cte.Product_ID
       FROM cte
            LEFT OUTER JOIN PRO_FAB
              ON cte.Fabric_ID = PRO_FAB.Fabric_ID
              AND PRO_FAB.Product_ID = cte.Product_ID
       WHERE PRO_FAB_ID IS NULL)
```

If your version of SQL doesn't support common table expressions, then you can use an inline subquery.

Comment: this doesn't get products using "all" fabrics, only products that use "any" fabrics.